# Working at an outsourcing company for a client. I want to work directly for the client's company

Tags: software-development, outsourcing

So I basically have little to no connection with my company. My direct supervisor works for the client's company, not the one I'm hired at. I work on the client's site. I also work exclusively with the people from the client's company. I've been here for almost 2 years.

I want to cut out my current employer and move directly to the client's company. Am I in the clear when it comes to legal stuff? How do I present this to my supervisor (he is also the decisionmaker)?

Comment: "Am I in the clear when it comes to legal stuff?" Check your contract, and for local laws contact a lawyer. If you are in the clear you can talk to your supervisor. However take in mind that this might backfire and you will most likely burn bridges.

Comment: Look at **all the paper work you signed** with the company writing your checks.  A location tag on this question would be helpful too.

Comment: Look up the laws. Even if the contract does not say so explicitly, there are arguments around dishonest behavior that may be codified in law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a copy of your employment contract. Does it specify anything about a non-compete clause? If not, you're probably golden (but read it all to be sure, and contact a lawyer if you don't understand any of the clauses).

As for how to speak to your supervisor, be honest:

> Hey [Name Here], I wanted to talk to you about a private matter. I've been delegated to you guys for almost 2 years now. To my mind, it would make sense if I jumped ship and were employed directly by you guys. What do you think about that idea?

And go from there.

I've known a bunch of people who ended up in situations like this, and it worked out well enough for them. Best of luck.

Comment: Usually the contract states that they contractor can be brought on to the company as long as a fee is paid to the contracting company.  Good answer.

Comment: @MisterPositive also in some jurisdictions remaining as a contract employee  for too long (commonly > 2 years) as well as failing some other test can automatically make you an employee Microsoft had this problem a few years ago

Answer (score 2):

IANAL (I Am Not a Lawyer)

Need to check your contract (employment agreement).

You could be in voilation of your contract if you even approach the client about direct hire.

Also the client may have a no poach clause in their contract with your employer.

Comment: Need to check your contract -- **yep**